# Google Sheets returning image links as images

Tags: google-sheets

So I currently have a sheet with links to photos. When I hover over these photos they appear as they are in my Google Drive.

The problem is, that I am trying to figure out a way to pull the images and return them to a cell.

Is there any way to do this?

[image: Picture of Images that I am trying to pull]

As you can see, I am trying to figure out a way to pull these images and return the actual image to the desired cell.

Comment: Hi, welcome to WebApps. When you say "links to photos", do you mean that you have used the `HYPERLINK` function?

Comment: Have you read [How find and use direct link to image uploaded in Google Drive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66978493/1330560) from StackOverflow. This is exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the link addresses with the [RichTextLinks](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/90697612?msgid=90848617) custom function, and then use the `image()` function in the next column to show the images.